# How to properly call a method with Stream?

Tags: scala, stream

I have a method that calls an API and returns a String. The API URI has a `page` parameter but I do not know how many pages there are. So I do an infinite call until the results are `[]`.

```
def getRequest(page: Int): String = {
//takes page argument, constructs an uri, and returns the api results
}

//infinite call until api result == "[]"
val results = Stream.from(0).takeWhile(x => getRequest(x) != "[]").map(getRequest(x))
```

I noticed my results makes two calls. One for the stream and then one for the map. How do I write it so I do not make two calls?

Comment: Maybe `val results = Stream.from(0).map(getRequest(_)).takeWhile(_ != "[]")` ?